# Prove that $c_1 \phi_1 + c_2 \phi_2$ solves the IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

> **Theorem:**
>
> If $\{ \phi_1, \phi_2\}$ is a fundamental set of solutions of
>   $$x''+p(t)x'+q(t)x=0,$$ then for any initial values $x(t_0)=x_0,
>  x'(t_0)=y_0$, there are constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that $c_1 \phi_1
>  + c_2 \phi_2$ solves the IVP.

I know that there is a standard way to prove this theorem, see also [How do we deduce that $c_1 \phi_1(x)+c_2 \phi_2(x)$ is a solution of the specific initial value problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166178/how-do-we-deduce-that-c-1-phi-1xc-2-phi-2x-is-a-solution-of-the-specifi)

However, my teacher puts down something like this:

> **Proof:**
>
> It is trivial since the IVP has at most one solution.

I don't see this coming! Maybe it is an easy question but I would appreciate if someone can explain this for me.